# C# GUI/WPF App, open the "new" W11 Console

Tags: c#, wpf, terminal, console

currently im using:

```
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern int AllocConsole();
```

to show a console window on a GUI app like WPF.
(for debugging purposes)

But this opens the "old" console.
[old console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebeb2.png)

If you create a .Net8 console app or start cmd.exe it is this console:
[new console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX61K.png)

there are new terminal settings in windows, where i also set only the new one, but i
guess the AllocConsole only starts the old one...

Any idea, whats the new api call for this?

EDIT:
[github of the new terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)

Comment: Doesn't `Process.Start("cmd.exe")` work?